# Getting error while uploading APK through intune to Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play-console

We created signed APK with keystore but while uploading we are getting "APK signature invalid or does not exist".
We are doing everything correct but we don't know why we are getting this error , please can any one help us what is the possibility.

Comment: You're probably not "doing everything correct" when signing with the wrong key or not at all ...

Comment: Before we do from continues integration but now we are generating manually from android studio

Answer (score 0):

Do you follow exact the same steps with this?
[Sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

and also, when your app is built, is the app's name is "-signed"?

Comment: We are updating existing build , using same keys no luck on this.

Comment: Can you double check with your keyStore path, keyStore password, keyAlias and keyPassword? Most probably the error is here because of "APK signature invalid or does not exist"

Comment: We taken care that carefully but no luck.